# Column is not iterable - apache spark dataframe - python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a column `int_rate` of type string in my spark dataframe and all its value are like `9.5%, 7.0%, etc`.

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0VLT.png) of how the column looks

Now I know that there is a way in which I can convert type string to float in python, but it is only applicable when the value would have be `9.5` without `%` symbol. I tried the following method:

```
df.int_rate = [x.strip('%') for x in df.int_rate]
```

given on this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-methods-to-remove-the-from-your-data-in-python-and-the-fastest-one-281489382455) to remove the `%` symbol, but it throws an error saying:

> Column is not iterable

I also tried the other methods listed on the [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/5-methods-to-remove-the-from-your-data-in-python-and-the-fastest-one-281489382455), but nothing seems to work. Can someone please help me to get rid of the `%` symbol and convert my column to type float?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame(["9.5%", "7.0%"], "string").toDF("int_rate")

df.withColumn("int_rate", expr("rtrim('%', int_rate)").cast("float")).show()
```

and another

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace

df.withColumn("int_rate", regexp_replace("int_rate", "%$", "").cast("float"))
```